# How to change button layout and position in Threepenny GUI?

Tags: haskell, threepenny-gui

How do I change the size and position of buttons or other UI elements in a GUI created with the threepenny-gui package?

The [documentation of `Graphics.UI.Threepenny.Attributes`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/threepenny-gui-0.8.3.0/docs/Graphics-UI-Threepenny-Attributes.html) lists some functions which are probably useful, such as `coords :: WriteAttr Element String`. However, I don't understand how to use them. Specifically, I don't understand what the `String` argument is supposed to be.

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/HeinrichApfelmus/threepenny-gui/blob/master/samples/Buttons.hs

Comment: @MichaelLitchard I'd say that is harsh. The OP clearly did some research (and not noticing a samples folder is something that can happen to anyone), and usage of Threepenny's layout combinators, as nice as they are, isn't exactly self-explanatory.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I had looked through all the sample files, including the one in the link, but I did not find any example where the size or position of buttons was modified. Looking at it again, I still do not see any example of this. I do think that I have found an answer to my question now, but if I understand correctly, I am supposed to post that as an answer instead of a comment, so I will do that.

Comment: @AR1981 Yup, self-answering is the right thing to do if you solved it yourself.

Comment: @duplode fair enough, downvote removed.

Answer (score 0):

I think my misunderstanding that I had was that my problem was not actually related to threepenny-gui but is instead a question about HTML. This link helped my find the answer I was looking for: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-attributes/

Just in case anyone else is struggling with this as well, this line (mostly) solves it:

```
# set UI.style [("text-align", "center"),("color","red"),("font-size","30px")]
```

(The UI in UI.style comes from: `import qualified Graphics.UI.Threepenny as UI`)

Comment: I suggest adding enough of the surrounding code to the question, so that folks reading this can see clearly what you have fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Threepenny UI element combinators translate more or less directly to HTML, and so you should think in terms of HTML when doing layout with it:

- The attributes from `Graphics.UI.Threepenny.Attributes` you mention are HTML attributes. Modifying them while defining your initial layout is typically done with [`set`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/threepenny-gui-0.8.3.0/docs/Graphics-UI-Threepenny-Core.html#v:set). (By the way, if you need a reference for looking up what things like HTML attributes do, you can't do wrong with [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes).)
- For CSS styling, you can use the [`(#.)` combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes).
- As for layout, the basic tools are [`(#+)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/threepenny-gui-0.8.3.0/docs/Graphics-UI-Threepenny-Core.html#v:-35--43-) to nest HTML elements, and [`grid`, `row` and `column`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/threepenny-gui-0.8.3.0/docs/Graphics-UI-Threepenny-Core.html#g:6) to arrange `div`-based grids.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I'll look into this. I do not know any HTML, therefore did not see the connection and did not understand that I had to google for HTML attributes instead of threepenny-gui attributes.